# How to style a `<ul>` element where is has no `li` elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `<ul>` container and a UI that allows me to add `<li>` elements into it on the fly. I want to apply different style to the `<ul>` when there is no `<li>` elements.

```
<ul class="con">
</ul>
```

```
ul.con:not(:has(> li)) {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border: 3px solid #000000 !important;
}
```

I am expecting the background color of the `ul` to change when there is 0 `li` elements. But, the style is not changing.

How can I correctly use the `:has()` selector or any other to style the `ul` elements when it has no `li` elements. Note: `:empty` selector does not work since there is a white space in the body of the `ul`.

Comment: Not on Firefox.

Comment: @MisterJojo thank you. I just realized this works on Chrome but not FireFox. How can we apply the same thing to work on Firefox also?

Comment: Looking at [:has() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), it says it's not supported in Firefox but you can explicitly enable it in the browser by going to `about:config` and setting `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` to `true`. Also, there isn't an alternative to `:has()`.

Comment: For an interim workaround until Firefox fully supports :has you could use CSS :empty but note that the ul must not even have whitespace so should look like <ul></ul> - not very nice if you usually use some tidying of the format.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you´re looking for. Note that if you **delete the *li*  tag** from the HTML, than the ***:not*** selector will act on the code:

```css
ul.con:not(:has(li)){
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid #000000 !important;
}

ul.con:has(li){
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

div:has(h1){
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1> Page title </h1>
    </div>

  <div>
    <ul class="con">
     <li> Item 1 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    ... another content ...
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```